# execCommand con varios contenteditable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, div

tengo una página con 3 div en contenteditable:

```
<div class="herra">
    <div title="Negreta"><b style="font-size: 2em;">N</b></div
    <div title="Cursiva"><i style="font-size: 2em;">K</i></div
    <div title="Subratllar"><u style="font-size: 2em;">S</u></div>
</div>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="txt1"></div>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="txt2"></div>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="txt3"></div>
<script>
    $($('.herra div')[0]).click(function() {document.execCommand('bold', false, null);});
</script>
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es poner el texto seleccionado del div que esté escribiendo en negrita, he probado con **`document.execCommand('bold', false, null);`** pero no me funciona.

Uso jquery. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes hacer un snippet de codigo con un ejemplo HTML y con el JS que haria la negrita? En la consola te salen fallos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira a ver si te sirve esto, al seleccionar un texto y pulsar en el botón se pone negrita:

```js
var negrita = document.getElementById("negrita");
negrita.addEventListener("click", function() { bold(); });

function bold() {
    document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
}
```

```html
<button href="#" id="negrita">Negrita</button> 
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="txt1">Texto1</div>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="txt2">Texto2</div>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" id="txt3">Texto3</div>
```

Comment: Funciona! hehe parece que lo diferente con lo que pueda tener él,. es el tercer parametro, que tú tienes `true`- Puedes enlazar documentacion o explicar qué es ese parametro? Otra posibilidad es que el autor no tenga bien hecho el evento de click y por eso no pase nada xD

Comment: Por lo que he visto cuando vas a utilizar "bold", el tercer parámetro no afecta, se puede poner un `null` o `""` sin ningún problema. (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1613/execcommand-and-contenteditable#t=201709011211249801555)

Comment: Entonces su problema debe estar en el evento. Por eso le pido que añada el snippet, para ver como lo tiene montado.

Comment: Edito el código para que ese parámetro no cree confusión.

Comment: Ya he puesto mi snipped

Comment: Tu código, Aitor, es el que ya tenía

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado, he cambiado los div para ponerlo en negrita por buttons